# WebView.goBack not working in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

In my application WebView.goBack not working, I have used following code in event listener

```
backButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     Titanium.UI.WebView.goBack();
});
```

How do I navigate to back?

Comment: What is the code of your webview object? can you please show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution should work for you.
In event listener use your webview object name instead of `Titanium.UI.WebView`

Suppose your webview is

```
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url:'http://www.appcelerator.com'});

backButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     webview.goBack();
});
```